# How to test the content of a PDF file

Tags: ruby, selenium, pdf

I'm trying to access  http://www.orimi.com/pdf-test.pdf to test if  "PDF Test File" exists.

This is my code:

```
it 'pdf test' do
        visit 'http://www.orimi.com/pdf-test.pdf'
        puts page.title
        sleep 5
        convert_pdf_to_page
        expect(page).to have_content 'PDF Test File'
end

def convert_pdf_to_page
        temp_pdf = Tempfile.new('pdf')
        temp_pdf << page.source.force_encoding('UTF-8')
        reader = PDF::Reader.new(temp_pdf)
        pdf_text = reader.pages.map(&:text)
        temp_pdf.close
        page.driver.response.instance_variable_set('@body', pdf_text)
end
```

But I got:

```
PDF::Reader::MalformedPDFError: PDF does not contain EOF marker
```

I searched and I found that the problem can be the PDF file. I checked the `temp_pdf` variable and there is just HTML with a empty body.

Is there something wrong in my code?

Comment: I would recommend verifying the contents of the PDF file without dynamically modifying the page during the test.

Comment: Hmmm... @dansalmo I tried but this is not worked, the problem is the third line of convert_pdf_to_page method

Comment: `it 'pdf test' do`? `it`?

Comment: @theTinMan `it` in capybara is an alias for `scenario` or `example`

Comment: @AdemDinarević I was taught that when designing a language it should follow some reasonable rules of grammar to help it to flow. "it" is... ugh.

Comment: @Matheus when I looked at that page, it was not a PDF.  It was an HTML page with an embedded PDF.  You need to get the source URL for the actual PDF file from the embed element and load that to test it.

Comment: @dansalmo, so I need to download the pdf file, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PDF is a tricky format, and different readers react differently to unexpected content in the PDF files. Some would crash, others would make assumptions to not crash.

I'd guess this is what happens here. When you open the file in the browser/pdf reader it works, but `PDF::Reader` can't handle whatever is not-standard there.

Try using different gem, [Origami](https://github.com/gdelugre/origami) seems to have good opinions. I tried it with your file, and it seems to work:

```
> require 'origami'
> pdf = Origami::PDF.read '/tmp/pdf-test.pdf'
> pdf.grep(/Not existing/).any?
=> false
> pdf.grep(/PDF Test File/).any?
=> true
```

---

For reference (how I came up with this answer):

I googled the `PDF::Reader::MalformedPDFError: PDF does not contain EOF marker` and found [this thread](https://github.com/yob/pdf-reader/issues/140), which suggests that it's a more common problem with "working" PDFs. One of the last messages suggests the [Origami](https://github.com/gdelugre/origami), which (after checking) seems to be able to handle the PDF in question.